# JMeter Number of Samplers does not seem to be going up to the correct amount after test

Tags: jmeter

As the title says, the number of samplers doesn't seem to be at the correct amount even after the test is run. In this test I am trying to test some APIs and they will be called 2000 times per minute for 60 minutes and one of the API's uploads a file and the filename changes every minute also. It gets the filenames from a CSV Data Set.
[image]

As you can see from the picture, there are only 30000 samples each request and I believe it should be 120,000 per request. Here are my Thread Properties.
[image]

I also have a Constant Throughput Timer in my Test Plan with target throughput as 2000 per minute. In one of my requests I also have a Constant Timer set for 60000 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

1. 4 Samplers
2. 2 000 virtual users
3. and want 120 000 total executions (30 000 executions of each sampler)

you need to set Loop Count to `15` in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

[image]

then you will get 2000 users * 4 Samplers * 15 loops == 120 000 total executions

Another option of limiting the number of executions for the particular Sampler is putting it under [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)

If you want to limit JMeter's throughput you can consider using more "precise" timers like [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) or [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)

Comment: The thing is I need it to run for one hour and each sampler should have 120,000 executions each

Comment: The thing is that in order to be able to get 120 000 executions of each sampler: 1. JMeter should be able to run requests fast enough. 2. Your application needs to be able to respond fast enough. If both criteria are met make sure to set "Calculate Throughput based on" to `all active threads (shared)`.

Comment: JMeter and the application both respond fast enough and changing "Calculate Throughput based on" to all active threads (shared) did not work for me. I wonder if it is because of the Constant Throughput Timer or maybe the Constant Timer I put under one of my samplers which is set to 60000ms